# Compositing a compound clip with transitions in FCP X

Tags: final-cut-pro-x

I have a compound clip with a flip transition in it, which I want to comp on the main timeline, while still showing the footage underneath.
(think flipping card composed on top of footage).

I've created a Compound Clip with the flip transition inside it, but the transition has a background colour set, so doesn't comp while transitioning (has a black background instead).

I've tried setting blend modes on the main timeline, but it just messes up the colour of the actual graphic.

Any ideas? Why can't the flip have a transparent background?